# How do I send message to different channel at the same time in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

My goal is to send a message to a channel that have the name `global-chat`.
I tried:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", async(msg) => {
   if(msg.channel.name !== "global-chat")return;
   let message = msg.content
   await client.channels.find("name", "global-chat").send(message)
})
```

but when I send message in the `global-chat` channel in one server, it won't send to `global-chat` on other servers. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send a message to the channel with the same name in all other guilds.

This line will simultaneously relay the message to *all* of the channels the bot is watching named `global-chat`. Here's how it works...

- [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) executes [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in a parallel manner.
- [`Client.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of channels the bot is watching. Using [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter), you can form a new Collection with just the channels named `global-chat`.
- [`Collection.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) returns an array of the values returned by the function provided for each value in the Collection. In this case, it returns an array of Promises for `Promise.all()` to use.

```js
await Promise.all(client.channels.filter(c => c.name === 'global-chat').map(c => c.send(msg.content)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use discord.js v12, you'll need to replace client.channels.filter by client.channels.**cache**.filter.